# Heard that WCF does not scale well with async methods?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have read in various blogs that WCF has a scalability problem with servicing a large number of concurrent async requests for an async WCF method. **Is this still true today in .Net 4.0 and IIS 7 world?**

By async method in WCF, I mean that async pattern has been implemented for this WCf method.

I checked this link: [WCF Scalability Issues with Async Pattern Method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234085/Fixing-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF not scaling was never true. What *was* true was that **applications did not scale**. (And this is still true, of course).

Honestly, when did you ever see a language or framework that did not scale? Requests are independent, meaning that they are embarrassingly parallel. This is a perfect situation for scaling.

The thing that impedes scaling is always the application. It happens when the app is either not written for high-scale or the code is of low quality.

To put it concretely: If you use WCF the way it is meant to be used, and go all the way async, you'll scale up to the hardware limits.

Comment: Usr - I agree with you but then I see this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826

Comment: This problem only comes into play if you misuse WCF by not being async while handling hundreds of concurrent requests. Async IO does not need threads while it is pending. Like I said: *Apps* don't scale.

Comment: Usr - I don't think async is the solution. If you closely look at the article, it says: 'Switch to the Async handler and then then apply the solution in this article or alternatively use a Private Threadpool (see links following this table)'. So you must apply a code-fix even after using async method in WCF. This means there is an inherent problem with WCF.

Comment: I meant that even when you use async, Microsoft recommends adding some extra code to WCF to allow for better performance at higher loads. Microsoft has clearly mentioned under than link I gave, that in .Net 4.0 and integrated mode in IIS, some extra code is needed for optimizing WCF performance at high loads when you have Async pattern implemented.

Comment: @Sunil, what they mean is "if you are sync right now, switch to fake-async by running your sync code on the thread-pool". If you had been truly async that would not have been necessary. This bug is triggered by user code blocking too many threads. Look at their code sample - it is sync code `Sleep` If it was async it would not be necessary to post to the thread-pool as no thread would be used at all!; Sunil, I have read the article thoroughly and I really believe it is as I say. I'm not arguing to defend WCF.